# How to find out learned words in Gboard?

Tags: privacy, gboard

Where can i find the words learned by google keyboard? I can't find nothing on the internet about where it is saved or how to find saved words that GBoard learned automatically.

Comment: If you're looking for the words that you have manually added, those you can find in Google keyboard app>dictionary>personal dictionary. If you're looking for words added automatically after using them many times, then i have the same question as you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it isn't possible. If you're talking about personal dictionary rather, it is in GBoard settings> Personal dictionary